# How does the set $\{ \mathbf{x} : F(\mathbf{x}) = \mu \}$ vary as $\mu$ varies?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am interested in the behavior of the set 
$Z(\mu) = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : F(\mathbf{x}) = \mu \} \cap D$ as $\mu$ varies, where $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial with integer coefficients and $D$ is a closed and bounded cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here I also want to assume that $D$ doesn't contain any points of $F$ that may act strangely, for example singular points or anything else that may make the analysis more complicated (I understand that this is rather vague, but I am just trying to get the idea).

The reason why I ask this is I want to show that the function 
$$
G(\mu) = \int_{Z(\mu)} 1 \ d \mathbf{x}
$$
is smooth, which I think should be the case... But I am really not sure how to proceed. Any explanations or comments are appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This function is the zero function unless $Z$ is constant. If $F$ is constant with value $\nu$, $G$ is discontinous, returning 0 when $\mu\neq \nu$ and $vol(D)$ when $\mu=\nu$.

For $F$ nonconstant, $V(F-\mu)\subset\Bbb A^n_{\Bbb R}$ is a subvariety of dimension $n-1$, which means that as topological spaces, $V(F-\mu)(\Bbb R)=F^{-1}(\mu)$ has dimension at most $n-1$, so it is a subset of measure zero.

Comment: Did you mean $F$ is constant in the first sentence? It looks like I may have oversimplified the problem... Let me try to fix this.

Comment: I edited the first sentence to make my meaning more clear. Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @JohnnyT. What means $\int_{Z(f-\mu) \cap D} 1 dx$ to you ? For example with $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1$, $V(f) = \{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2, f(x_1,x_2) = 0\}$ how do you compute $\int_{V(f) \cap [-1,1]^2} 1 dx$ ? Giving to it the correct meaning (hyper-surface integral) then the question should be more interesting : the integral is locally smooth in the coefficients of $f$, except at some points where interesting things happen.